# Get single unicode string from digest::hmac

Tags: python, r, hmac, digest

How can I get a single unicode string as the signature below (instead of a character vector (which seems to contain pieces of unicode strings)?

For example

```
  library(digest)

  raw_key = 'QQrawkeyrawkeyrawkeyrawkey4='
  key = RCurl::base64Decode(raw_key)
  url_test = 'example_url'
  signature <- digest::hmac(key, url_test, algo = "sha1", raw = T)
```

Returns the character vector

64 d9 cb 13 d3 f9 5c 0a 4c 1d 47 d2 d5 9d ab 24 25 3f f3 20

But I want it to return the single string
'd\xd9\xcb\x13\xd3\xf9\\nL\x1dG\xd2\xd5\x9d\xab$%?\xf3 '

**Background:**

I am trying to make the R code work the same as the python code below (I am not very experienced with python).

```
     raw_key = 'QQrawkeyrawkeyrawkeyrawkey4='
     key = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(raw_key)
     url_test = 'example_url'
     hmac.new(key, url_test.encode(), hashlib.sha1).digest()
```

Additional context is that I need to string to create the signature for a call to the google distance matrix API using a premium account.

Comment: Seems to work, many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`digest::hmac(.., raw=TRUE)` isn't actually returning a character vector, it's returning a "raw" vector in R. To convert this to a string, use

```
rawToChar(signature)
```